# For some reason, electron-packager is not able to find electron... Any idea what to do?

Tags: node.js, json, electron, electron-packager

For some reason, electron-packager can't find the module electron. I have installed it as instructed from the official site, yet it doesn't seem to work. Here is what seems to happen, my package.json, and how I run electron-packager

Package.json

```
{
"name": "electron-part1",
"version": "1.0.0",
"description": "An electron tutorial",
"main": "index.js",
"jquery": "^3.3.1",
"scripts": {
    "start": "electron .",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
},
"author": "Me",
"license": "ISC",
"devDependencies": {
    "electron": "^5.0.3",
    "electron-packager": "^8.7.2"
},
"dependencies": {
    "custom-electron-titlebar": "^3.2.5",
    "jquery": "^3.5.1"
}
}
```

What happens:
[image]

How I call electron-packager:
electron-packager . electron-part1 --platform=win32 --arch=x64

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it! If anyone else is having the same problem, copy electron from %USERPROFILE%\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules, and paste it to node modules in your main folder (The one with package.json) then you can package it as normal